# Python -Seaborn heatmap bind to mouse click event

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, heatmap, seaborn, mouseclick-event

I am developing a simple (so far) GUI on tkinter.
What I have right now is a GUI window with a `canvas` object and a treeview table in the same window.
My aim is to load `csv` data generate a heat map and use the positions to show further data about the clicked locations. 
I can already generate the heat map(picture below) from the `csv`.

What I need now is for the `canvas` to detect my mouse click and based on the click transfer data from the same (or a different it doesn't matter as of yet) `csv` to the table. I tried a few things but I quite don't seem to understand how to assign the data on the canvas or the table for it to recognize it.

```
        def tableDisplayFromGraph(self):
        tableframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        tableframe.grid(row=2, column=10, ipadx=4, pady=2, sticky ="e")  ## Packing against tableframe Frame

        COLUMNS = ['Type', 'Value']  ## Column Headers for Data

        ## See Documentation for more info on Treeview
        table = ttk.Treeview(tableframe, columns=COLUMNS, show='headings', padding=4)
        table.grid(row=0, column=0)

        for column in COLUMNS:  ## Setting Column Header
            table.heading(column, text=column)

        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(tableframe, command=table.yview)  ## Adding Vertical Scrollbar
        scroll.grid(row=0, column=1) # problem how to set scrollbar inside the table :/
        table.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)  ## Attach Scrollbar :/

    def canvas(self):

        f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=110)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        if not self.Data.empty:

            pivot_table = self.Data.pivot('Rows', 'Columns', 'B635 Mean')
            plt.xlabel('Columns', size=12)
            plt.ylabel('Rows', size=12)
            plt.title('Heat Map', size=15)
            sns.heatmap(pivot_table, annot=True, annot_kws={'size': 8},fmt="0.0f", linewidths=0, square=True, cmap='Reds')
        #a.clear()

        canvasFig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.master)
        canvasFig.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=5, padx=30, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        navigatorFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        navigatorFrame.grid(row=21, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=30, sticky="nw")

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvasFig, navigatorFrame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvasFig._tkcanvas.grid()
        f.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.pick)

    def pick(self, event):

        if canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
            canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="blue")
            canvas.update_idletasks()
            canvas.after(200)
            canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="red")

        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.pick)enter code here
```

When I hover around the heat map the canvas doesn't show x,y coordinates.
pick is my function for the click event.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the image of my GUI. On the left is my heat map and on the right is my table treeview widget for displaying further data:

[image]

Comment: You need `event.xdata, event.ydata` to get the data coordinates of the clicks. Apart this question is much too broad. And it lacks a [mcve] (surely no complex GUI is needed to solve the actual issue).

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Maybe a complex GUI isn't required to fix this issue since I can generate such plots in `R` pretty easily using `Plotly`. But I need to later work with further data and more complex functionalities which requires me to make a complex GUI. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest